# Covariant derivative as a connection on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

In the Wikipedia article [Connexion (vector bundle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_%28vector_bundle%29), such a connection is defined as a function $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ . Then the definition of a covariant derivative is given as a function $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$. But the article proceeds by saying that a covariant derivative is also a connection.

- How could a covariant derivative be a connection since the codomains
  of those two kinds of objects appear to be different ?
- Are those two different definitions of a connection ? Some authors would use the $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ version, while others would use $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You differentiate in the direction of some vector (field). Feeding in the vector field is going to remove the $\otimes T^*M$ :)

**EDIT**: To be concrete, given the map $D\colon\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$, a section $s$, and a vector field $X$ on $M$, we have $Ds \in\Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ with $(Ds)(X) = \nabla_X s$. This is the "classic" covariant derivative in the direction of $X$.
In coordinates, if $s_1,\dots, s_r$ give a (local) basis for sections of $E$ and $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^n$ give a (local) basis for sections of $T^*M$, $D$ is defined by
$$D(s_i) = \sum_{\substack{1\le j\le r\\ 1\le k\le n}} a_{ik}^j s_j\otimes\omega^k \quad\text{for some functions } a_{ik}^j.$$
Then the covariant derivative viewpoint is given by
$$\nabla_X(s_i) = \sum_{j,k} a_{ik}^j \omega^k(X)s_j.$$

Comment: I get that, my question is why would the new object be considered a connection as well ?

Comment: It's just a question of whether you think of a derivative as an abstract operator or as a directional derivative in a certain direction. It's still the same object. For the latter notion in your question, you need to start with a vector field $X$ on $M$, and then you get a map $\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$.

Comment: So, a connection is always a $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ function, and since there is a bijection between the spaces of covariant derivatives and connections (obtained from the contraction), a covariant derivative uniquely defines a connection ?